# how to change the @ and @tmp directory creation in jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, devops

Every time my build is running, i got 2 or 3 folders with @ and @tmp

**Example:** If my build name is test, I run the build it fetches some code from git and store it in the jenkins workspaces with names test, test@2 test@2tmp test@tmp. But original folder is test. I only want the test folder and i need to remove the next 2 folders. How can i do this. 
My present working directory is automatically choosing as test@2

- I want the default pwd to be /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/
- I want to delete the @2 and @tmp files and change my working directory to  after the build runs

### Sample output is:

- pwd
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test@2

Answer (score 2):

You can use **customWorkspace** in your jenkins pipelines:

**Example:**

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'my-label'
        customWorkspace '/my/path/to/workspace'
    }
}
```

**Note** that Jenkins use different directories to support concurrent builds:

> If concurrent builds ask for the same workspace, a directory with a suffix such as @2 may be locked instead.

Since you don't want this behaviour I advise you to use **disableConcurrentBuilds** option:

> Disallow concurrent executions of the Pipeline. Can be useful for preventing simultaneous accesses to shared resources, etc. For example: `options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }`

References on **customWorkspace** and **disableConcurrentBuilds**: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: pipeline {
   agent any
       options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
//codes

I used disableConcurrentBuilds like this, but it doesn't work

Comment: can you further explain why it didn't work? what was the behavior?

Comment: pipeline {
   agent any
   options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    } // I used the option in the first of my pipeline. 

When i put the code node{customworkspace under agent it reflects an error like this. 
WorkflowScript: 17: Only one agent type is allowed per agent section @ line 17, column 13.
WorkflowScript: 17: No agent type specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, label, none] @ line 17, column 13.
               agent {
               ^

Comment: When i invoke the docker image, Then it will change the work space to some other tmp directory. I use disable concurrent builds, no change in the result. If i have only one folder with one build it will be ok. Any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

look for agent{ } block in your pipeline groovy script. it should be only at the pipeline block level and not into any stage block.